# Flask long routines

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, long-running-processes

I have to do some long work in my Flask app. And I want to do it async. Just start working, and then check status from javascript.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
@app.route('/sync')
def sync():
    p = Process(target=routine, args=('abc',))
    p.start()

    return "Working..."
```

But this it creates defunct gunicorn workers.

How can it be solved? Should I use something like Celery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many options. You can develop your own solution, use Celery or Twisted (I'm sure there are more already-made options out there but those are the most common ones).

Developing your in-house solution isn't difficult. You can use the `multiprocessing` module of the Python standard library:

- When a task arrives you insert a row in your database with the task id and status.
- Then launch a process to perform the work which updates the row status at finish.
- You can have a view to check if the task is finished, which actually just checks the status in the corresponding.

Of course you have to think where you want to store the result of the computation and what happens with errors.

Going with Celery is also easy. It would look like the following.
To define a function to be executed asynchronously:

```
@celery.task
def mytask(data):

    ... do a lot of work ...
```

Then instead of calling the task directly, like `mytask(data)`, which would execute it straight away, use the `delay` method:

```
result = mytask.delay(mydata)
```

Finally, you can check if the result is available or not with `ready`:

```
result.ready()
```

However, remember that to use Celery you have to run an external *worker* process.

I haven't ever taken a look to Twisted so I cannot tell you if it more or less complex than this (but it should be fine to do what you want to do too).

In any case, any of those solutions should work fine with Flask. To check the result it doesn't matter **at all** if you use Javascript. Just make the view that checks the status return JSON (you can use Flask's `jsonify`).

Comment: Well, I really have everything that you said about storing results in DB. The main problem with implementing my own solution is that when I'm using `multiprocessing` it causes gunicorn worker to be defunct.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry I misread your question. It looks like your problem is that your parent process is terminating after the return statement, which effectively kills the child process you have just created. To avoid that, you just have to daemonize the child before the parent exits (i.e. detach it) [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/)

Comment: I get `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` when use it with multiprocessing. Looks like I need to use Popen. Setting `Process().daemon = True` also does not help.

Comment: Yes, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) `p.daemon = True` is not enough. If you're on a \*nix platform I would use [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) or use this [snipped](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/) that makes direct OS calls to `fork`, instead of `multiprocessing` or `Popen`. If you're in Windows you have to create a *service* instead of a daemon. And in any case, the most portable solution can be to use Celery or Twisted.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a message broker such as rabbitmq or activemq. The flask process would add jobs to the message queue and a long running worker process (or pool or worker processes) would take jobs off the queue to complete them. The worker process could update a database to allow the flask server to know the current status of the job and pass this information to the clients.

Using celery seems to be a nice way to do this.

Comment: Can you please share an example of creating a long running worker process to read from the queue